# Can we use a single aws data pipeline to run every Monday, Wednesday Friday , with out creating multiple pipelines. If we can, how so?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-data-pipeline

Can we use a single AWS data pipeline to run every Monday, Wednesday Friday, without creating multiple pipelines? If we can, how so?